# How to make desktop lock immediate?

Tags: unity, lock-screen

I don't like the delayed fade-out effect for locking the workstation. I'd like the lock screen to appear immediately after pressing keyboard shortcut for locking (Ctrl-Alt-L). How to configure this? I didn't find anything in system settings.

I also tried searching Dconf setting database with `gsettings list-recursively | grep lock` and didn't find a appropriate key...

Comment: "*fading out*" ....  do you mean the "curtain"-effect ?

Comment: I think you are referring to the Unity graphical effects. AFAIK there is no way to disable it just for the lock-screen. You can use Low-Graphic Mode to disable all effects. See http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/11/enable-low-graphics-mode-unity-7-ubuntu If this works for you I will convert this to a full answer.

Comment: @user68186 Thanks, but this is not a good solution for me :(

Comment: @RobertRiedl I'm not sure what the proper name is. I'd just like to have no effect, just immediate blackout.

Comment: No problem. I am sorry I don't have any other solution.